# 100 amp service wire size from transformer to meter/panel

Tags: wiring

I have a run of 185ft underground in 2 1/2" conduit from transformer to my a 100 amp service panel/meter. What size wire should I use?

Comment: Sorry, Dean but I'm going to rant for a moment.   This sort of question has been asked and answered thousands of times here. A simple search of even just this site would give you an answer. Not only that, there are many online resources such as https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop      ......Expectations here are that you do as least some basic research on your own rather than ask us to do your work for you.

Comment: I have researched, talked to 2 certified electrician's. I get different answers. And yes there are others asking similar questions, but I am asking specifically about 185ft distance, not 100ft, 150ft, etc. So, Thought I would ask on here. If it bothers you please skip past this question to another.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to assume you just "came here first"!   It's just that it's tiresome to get the same question over and over again. But since you did some homework first I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: thank you. Maybe you can answer this simple question as well. I have two answers on this as well. Same installation, but for 200 amp. I got aluminum 4/0 4/0 2/0 and 4/0 4/0 4/0 for answers. I know this has been asked on here as well. But again, I am asking about a specific distance. If you are asking your self why I am asking both of these scenarios it's because I am trying to decide if I want to go 100 amp or 200 amp. I was planning 100 amp, but running 200 amp wire to upgrade at a later date, but 100 amp meter will not accept 4/0 wire (so the manufacture told me) 1/0 was the largest.

Comment: This is to just for RV hookups for now

Comment: 4/4/2 is fine for a 200 amp service.   Why not just upgrade the meter base now? They aren't expensive.  Also 200 amp panels are extremely common, the cost difference between a 100 amp panel and 200 amp panel could be as low as $20-$40. Why put yourself thru the pain of a panel upgrade just a few years down the road?    Again, sorry for getting snippy earlier!

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your time. Yes, I know and I am starting to lean that way. Only thing is the power company wants an additional 1000.00 to upgrade to 200 amp service and to be honest I may never need it.     From my reading of charts from Wire manufactures they say 2 1/2" schedule 80 is adequate for 4/0 wire. Would you agree

Comment: Yes, 2.5" is great, will make for an easy "pull".  I believe 2" is also acceptable, but I like to go big bc it's just easier.   ....so your POCO wants a grand to upgrade? Not sure what to suggest next, maybe others with more experience will chime in.  The only thing I can think of is get some connectors that accept both 4/0 and 2/0 and run some very short 2/0 wires to the lugs on the MB.  You'll probably have to downgrade the main breaker on the panel to 100 amps, but at least you'll be set up for 200, if the time comes.

Comment: Well, I though of what you are saying too, to have 200 amp meter and change breaker to 100 amp, but the PUD will not allow you to use 200 amp meter unless I have 200 amp service. I am just going to go with 200 amp service. It's becoming a pain to try deal with 100 amp equipment using 200 amp wire. I appreciate your feed back and you have helped me to make a choice of going to 200 amp.

Comment: I just heard back from the L&I inspector. He said 4/0 4/0 2/0 is fine. Not required to upsize the neutral. He said to have electrician do a voltage drop calculation to see if it would support things like AC, heat pump if wanted. Can you tell me? no more then 2000 sq ft, 3 bedroom, 2 bath home running 4/0 4/0 2/0 no more then 200 ft max

Comment: To @GeorgeAnderson's point, it's good that you did your research before asking. It's even better if you share the results of your research and why you're still confused. That helps prevent the frustration that he shared.

Answer (score 2):

### Voltage drop may be an issue, at this distance.

The Canadian Rule (don't permit more than 3% voltage drop at 80% of breaker trip, which is the max provisionable) requires a wire size "bump" around the 175' mark on distance.  This is not required in the United States, but it's a viable rule of thumb.   Under the Canadian Rule

- for 100A breaker (80A computed) #1 will come in at 2.99% drop.
- for 200A breaker (160A computed) #4/0 will come in at 2.88% drop.

And that's fine, because those are your minimum wire sizes *anyway*.

### Wires carrying *your whole service* get a 17% discount

When you have wires carrying *your entire service*, you get to compute your *mandatory* wire sizes off 83% of service size.   So this leads us to #2Al for 100A, and #4/0Al for 200A.

A feeder wire never needs to be bigger than the service wire by this rule.

However, since you are seriously contemplating a 200A heavy-up, I do not recommend laying #2 because you'd only need to upgrade it later.

### All other feeders need to calculate on full-boat

If a feeder doesn't benefit from the above exception, then it must calculate full-boat ampacity.  For the wire types offered in aluminum, that is

100A = #1 Al ...... 200A = 250 kcmil Al.

### A 2-RV stands needs less than 100A.

The RV provisioning rules allow a "discount" for feeder size when the feeder serves multiple RV stands.  The discount means #2 aluminum wire (rated full-boat 90A) is acceptable to feed two 50A RV stands.

### Run wires ONCE

The reason I'm arming you with all this data is because I want you to not have to replace wires later.  Run the wire you need and don't look back.

"But my 100A meter won't take 4/0 wire!"  That's OK -- get three Polaris connectors rated for 4/0.  Use those to pigtail down to #2 or #1 Al wire to land on the meter lugs.  Of course those Polaris couplers are about $20 a pop, so figure that into the cost.

### On panels - think BIG

What's important with panels is the number of *breaker spaces*.  Spaces are dirt cheap, so never allow a future situation where  you want to add a circuit or feeder *but can't because the panel is full*.  Honestly, "help, my panel is full" is our #1 panel question here.  Just get ridiculous numbers of spaces.

Typically, 100A panels have only a few spaces... most panels of respectable size (24-space and larger) are 200A bussed.  If they are main-breaker, they typically have 200A main breakers.

That is fine -- you can go ahead and use it anyway.  If it is downstream of another breaker, then the local breaker doesn't matter - it's only there to be a disconnect switch.   E.G. if you use a 100A "meter-main" you can run to a 200A-main-breaker panel and that's fine - the 200A breaker serves merely as a disconnect so its size doesn't matter.

If this panel *needs* a 100A breaker, then you have 3 choices:

- Buy a 200A main-breaker panel and swap out the main breaker for 100A
- Buy a 200A main-breaker panel, *disregard* the 200A main, and install a 100A breaker in a normal breaker space and backfeed it, as the main. Label it as the main breaker.
- Buy a 200A/225A *convertible, main-lug* panel, and buy a retrofit main breaker that is 100A.

Comment: 3 or 4 Polaris connectors @ $20 each are going to be much cheaper than small wire now and replacement big wire (plus the Polaris connectors anyway) later!

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate Monica - Thank you for the detailed information. You when over my head is a few places, but from what I gathered. You are saying I am good to use 4/0 4/0 2/0 without any issues on 200 amp future service? I totally agree that to run the big wire now, which has been my plan anyway. I was just trying to save 1000.00 up front on the upgrade from 100 amp service to 200 amp service, since I have no immediate plans to upgrade, if at all. If I wait, it could cost me more to do at a later time. So, I think i have talked myself into just going with 200 amp service and equipment now.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate Monica - Since you brought up Panels. I am trying to decide on panel type & style of breakers. Recommendation? PUD told me for their requirements is it needs to be Ring type and no bypass. But I see breakers that are Plug on, BR, Etc. I just want it to be safe, reliable and not spend a ton. I am likely going to go with a 200 amp meter/panel combo. I really don't want more then 8 to 16 breaker knockouts. They will never all get used, at least by me, in my life time. If I build a house, the meter/panel would not be used anyway. I am finding it confusing to say the least.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate Monica - Additional Panel Info - This installation is going to be outside, mounted on Post/plywood backing. The 200 amp meter / panel will be mounted, the RV panel will be mounted the right side and connected with PCV conduit. So I need size knockout on the right side of Service Panel to feed over to RV panel (which i have selected and has side knockout)

Comment: @Dean like I was saying, you CAN run 200A wire and use a 100A meter/main.  Just need to pigtail the wire size down to what the meter can handle.  Since you can live with 8 spaces, you might consider a "Farm Panel" - it has a main breaker, 8 breaker spaces (only), *and then, it has thru lugs*.  So you are able to tap your 100A or 200A with up to four 240V circuits (2 spaces per breaker with 240V) ... and then you come off the thru-lugs and continue the **entire** 100A or 200A onto another building.  It's very typical to put farm panels outside e.g. on a pole.

Comment: In fact, I would install a 200A farm panel below a 100A meter, and simply change the 200A main breaker to a 100A.  Then later, when you decide to heavy-up, a) change meter pan to 200A b) change service entrance wires from #2 to #4/0,  c) put 200A main breaker in, and d) done.

Comment: @Harper-Reinstate Monica - Yes I know you said I can pig tail. But I am just going to do 200 amp because at a later date they could charge me more to upgrade service to 200amp. This way I am locked in and It makes it easier. Hopefully i will end up using it. I am going to go with something like a CH 200 Amp 8-Space 8-Circuit EUSERC Main Breaker Meter Breaker Ranch Panel by Eaton or something very similar. Then I can add a 100 amp breaker to feed my 100 amp RV panel and have additional slots if needed to add for shed or other out buildings. Thoughts on this panel? or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If running aluminum (which is fine), 2/0 is the right size for 100 amps. You also have to consider what you are running is it a continuous load, like lamps for a grow operation? Bitcoin mining?  Or just a residence / outbuilding/ shop/ garage? If not a continuous high load, voltage drop is much less of an issue. Running a few light fixtures and small tools in a shop would result in virtually no voltage drop on AL 2/0. So voltage drop calculations totally depend upon the planned load.

You'll need to check with local codes to see if you need over-current protection at the meter, or if the 100 amp breaker in the panel would suffice. There are changes in the NEC regarding access to external disconnects (think fire fighters, first responders) that mandate the ability to quickly cut power to structures in the case of an emergency.

I got a little "prickly" with you at first and apologize for that.

Comment: Would that be all sizes 2/0 (2/0 2/0 2/0)